# IE6 floated labels

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Another IE6 (and 7) float problem.
I've some `label`s at right and some `input`s, `textarea` and `span` at left.
http://jsfiddle.net/VRErj/1/

How can I fix it?

**Edit:** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEB64.png)

Comment: What is the problem? Can you give a screenshot? Most people browsing this site probably aren't using IE 6 or 7 so it is harder for people to help without more explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately adding `clear` and `float` in the same CSS class does not work as expected in IE7 and below. You will have to add an additional clearing element after the element you want to `clear`.

Comment: @Jeff: yes, i've added a screenshot.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: thanks, how to do it? could you please edit my example?

Comment: @kikio Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VRErj/3/ I have also removed `display: block` from your classes as `float` does this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As My Head Hurts mentioned, clearing is a pain in IE 7 and below. You can wrap your label/input pairs in a div and apply the `clearfix` class to it that you get on this page: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html. It would look something like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="input1">input 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="input2">input 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" />
</div>
<!--etc...-->
```

That should do it.